# php: Get file information with readdir

Tags: php

I am using this piece of code to get the list of audio files in a directory.

```
if ($handle = opendir($directory_url)) {

    while (false !== ($entry = readdir($handle))) {

        if ($entry != "." && $entry != "..") {

            $ext = pathinfo($entry, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
            $audio_ext = array('mpeg', 'ogg', 'wav', 'webm', 'mp3');

            if(in_array(strtolower($ext),$audio_ext)) {

                echo $entry;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I also want to read other related information of the files such as title, album and if possible length of the audio track. I searched Filesystem functions: http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_ref_filesystem.asp. But couldn't find a solution.

can anyone please help me with this?

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/ref.id3.php Or, even better: http://getid3.sourceforge.net/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

additional Information ist stored differently in the different file types.

For Example: mp3 uses the "id3" tag to save informations like title, album and so on.

If you want to read id3 data you can simply do something like this:

```
<?php
// will return an array
$tag = id3_get_tag( "example.mp3", ID3_V2_3 );
?>
```

`$tag` will be an array of ID3 Infromations.
The Second Paramenter of the Function ist the ID3 Version the file uses. To get the Version of the ID3 Tag for the specific file you can use the function `id3_get_version("example.mp3")`.

Find more Informations in the official PHP Doc http://php.net/manual/en/function.id3-get-version.php